# Accessing DOM from within linking function scope.$watch: replace set to true vs false

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to manipulate the DOM from within my linking function.

I noticed that when i set replace to false, I am able to access the DOM (http://jsfiddle.net/bcsU8/)

```
//body of directive
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
        bar: '@myDir'
    },
    template: '<div id="{{bar}}">foo bar is <span>{{bar}}</span></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.$watch('myDir', function(value) {
            console.log('In watch - scope.bar: ', scope.bar);
            console.log('DOM accesible? ', $("#"+scope.bar).length == 1);
        });
    }
};
```

but when I set it to true I can't (http://jsfiddle.net/PpXgb/)

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        bar: '@myDir'
    },
    template: '<div id="{{bar}}">foo bar is <span>{{bar}}</span></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.$watch('myDir', function(value) {
            console.log('In watch - scope.bar: ', scope.bar);
            console.log('DOM accesible? ', $("#"+scope.bar).length == 1);
        });
    }
};
```

Why am I not able to access the DOM when replace is on?  I have not found anything in the documentation to indicate there should be a difference between these 2 cases.

From the docs on linking function it sounds like the DOM is available after the linking process: (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Post-linking function
Executed after the child elements are linked. **It is safe to do DOM transformation in the post-linking function.**

Please note that in my scope.$watch I'm actually calling a jQuery plugin that expects the DOM to be there, not accessing elements directly via $()

Comment: Side note - you may be aware of this already, but in your examples the `ng-repeat="bar in foo"` should be on the `li` not the `ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue in this case is that the element is not yet attached to the DOM when the `link` function is run. This is not really an issue for what you're trying to do; the issue is that you're breaking a best practice by trying to access the element not through the `element` object passed to the `link` function, but through a jQuery selector. Try using the `element` object and I think you'll find your code suddenly works.

But there are caveats to the execution order of directive methods, so there are *some* cases where this still wouldn't work, but you're not likely to encounter them in a basic directive. Just the same, you should read [the guide page on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) to get a better understanding of how AngularJS treats directives.

Comment: In my code i'm calling a function in the watch that expects the dom to be there.  I'm console logging to show the DOM state that the function experiences which is that DOM is sometimes available and sometimes not available in the linking function.

Comment: You can't do this. AngularJS does not guarantee the nodes to be appended to the DOM when the `link` function runs. Depending on your use case, a `postLink` function might work better. But I can't say anything more specific without knowing what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm using highcharts jQuery plugin which renders svg charts into divs.  I'm inputing the chart divs with ng-repeat bound to a model containing all the charts.  Within the watch function I have a call to highcharts.  It works if the divs are there and fails if not.  I did try this using compile postLink as well but it did not work because I'm passing chart id as an attribute (that's what scope.bar represents in the example).

Comment: I'm not a Highcharts expert, but it looks like you can pass a reference to the DOM element instead: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.renderTo. That is, just pass `element` instead of `scope.bar`. Does that work?

Comment: No it gives me: Error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'a.setAttribute(b,c)') in Safari and TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setAttribute' in Chrome

Comment: It looks like it allows a jQuery object, but it's trying regular DOM functions. Use `element[0]` and see if that works.